# GitLab Integration with HP ALM

Tags: git, gitlab, hp-alm

Has anyone integrated GitLab with HP ALM. Will it be able to trigger the ALM tests once build is triggered from GitLab

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exact workflow you have in mind, but you can probably have a look at the [Agiletestware Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee).
It has possibility to trigger tests in ALM from some CI system like Jenkins, Bamboo or TeamCity.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of Bumblebee

Comment: I am looking for test case execution in HP ALM once build is triggered in git lab.

Comment: @Shwetha We were doing some R&D for such an integration and have some solution which is not yet publicly available. But you can contact us via our website - we will be happy to send it over to you

Comment: Can you please share the website details

Comment: @Shwetha, sure - you can either navigate to https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee and then click on Support->Contact Us, or directly navigate to https://agiletestware.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/2